# Laravel 7- How do I send emails in laravel using SendinBlue?

Tags: laravel, api

I am trying to send emails in Laravel using the [Sendinblue API](https://www.sendinblue.com/?utm_source=bingads_brand&utm_medium=lastclick&utm_content=SendinBlue&utm_extension&utm_term=sendinblue&utm_matchtype=e&utm_campaign=EN_Asia_Search_Brand_Test_CPA_Bing_SIB&bing_campaignid=278665455&utm_network=o&km_adid=76347411643288&km_adposition&km_device=c&utm_adgroupid=1221557616034045&msclkid=c9fd72999f4017464baf2d3ba2d114f5) but the problem is, I don't know how to configure the files (.env file, config/mail file,etc.)

Here are the details that I have (that are registered in sendinblue). I edited some data so that the important details are not visible.

**Email address** registered in sendinblue-xxxx@xxxx.com

**Company/organisation** registered in sendinblue -xxxxOrganization

Sendinblue details page 1

[image]

Sendinblue details page 2

[image]

Other email services have proper Laravel documentations, but since we are testing, we need free email services for a few emails. And we preferred sendinblue for our tests as well.

Comment: You can try this library
https://github.com/agence-webup/laravel-sendinblue

Comment: @Al-Amin What is the access key in that repo?

Comment: with respect to my details?

Comment: just set in you .env `SENDINBLUE_KEY= your_api_key`, api_key available in your first screenshot

Comment: @Al-Amin Nope that does not work. ALthough I am not getting an error message, but I am not gettint the emails either

Comment: "[401] Client error: `POST https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:\n{\"code\":\"unauthorized\",\"message\":\"Key not found\"}\n",

Comment: getting this error

Comment: check your `SENDINBLUE_KEY`, make sure `.env` after modify clear cache if cached

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I have to email sendinblue support to Activate Sendinblue SMTP account. Make sure that yours is activated.

Then, here is the config that worked for me:

```
    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.sendinblue.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=mylogin@gmail.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD="master_password_or_smtp_key_value"
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="no-reply@mydomain.com"
```

where:
MAIL_USERNAME is the "Login" value in "Your SMTP settings" (not SMTP Key Name)
MAIL_PASSWORD is either Master password or SMTP Key Value

Comment: Did you do any *other* change than in the **.emv** file?

Comment: No, that's all. And don't forget to secure your .env file. Some one will try to steal your sendinblue information

Comment: Um, since I tried before and couldn't do it, I used Gmail services to test emails to real people. I shall try your methods again and let you know. Thanks anyways.